# Progressbar in for loop

Tags: android, android-progressbar, layout-inflater

I'm trying this code but, just 3rd progress Bar updated.
i want to know what is my mistake in the code?

```
package com.yasi.testview;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    LayoutInflater inflater;
LinearLayout scrollContent;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        scrollContent = findViewById(R.id.scrollContent);

        for (int i=1; i<4; i++){
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.test_item,scrollContent);
            ProgressBar progressBar = findViewById(R.id.prgDownload);
            TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.txtDownload);

            progressBar.setProgress((int) (Math.random() * 100));
            textView.setText("Download # " + i);

        }


    }
}
```

and this a picture of my project:
[Project screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9djkF.jpg)

a scroll view  is in main activity layout by this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/scrollContent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

and my test_item layout is code below that contains a progress bar and a text view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/prgDownload"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtDownload"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="..." />
</RelativeLayout>
```

thank you for your answers.

Comment: Post your activity layout file. I can see the issue but would explain better with the xml.

Comment: You're only changing one ProgressBar in your code.

Answer (score 0):

First of all don't get new instances of elements in loop again and again it is a poor approach as resolved in snippet below, secondly you are just using one progress bar over and over again and updating it on same thread, u need to have more progress bars in xml and also you can generate dynamically and then u can run the loop and update accordingly.

```
package com.yasi.testview;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    LinearLayout scrollContent;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        **View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.test_item,scrollContent);
        ProgressBar progressBar = findViewById(R.id.prgDownload);
        TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.txtDownload);**
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        scrollContent = findViewById(R.id.scrollContent);

        for (int i=1; i<4; i++){
            progressBar.setProgress((int) (Math.random() * 100));
            textView.setText("Download # " + i);

        }


    }
}
```

Comment: If u need more progress bars then make more. otherwise single progressbar is not going to work.

Answer (score 0):

Declare widgets-Views outside of loop and use this code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.test_item, scrollContent);

    scrollContent = findViewById(R.id.scrollContent);
    ProgressBar progressBar = findViewById(R.id.prgDownload);
    TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.txtDownload);

    for (int i=0; i < 3; i++){

            progressBar.setProgress((int) (Math.random() * 100));
            textView.setText("Download # " + i);

        }

   }
```

As you can see, **you're making changes to only `ProgressBar`** with `prgDownload` id so, **you'll probably need to declare more `ProgressBar`s in your project**.

**Edit:**

To show `ProgressBar` programmatically, use this:

```
progressBar = new ProgressBar(activity, null, android.R.attr.progressBarStyleSmall);
```

You can use this inside `for` loop for three items but, the way you're trying to show inside loop **is not recommended**.

Comment: Oh. Sounds like you're trying to show multiple `ProgressBar`s inside that loop, i get it now. Updated the annswer.